# choosing "some" of the provided comboboxes to filter choices in data gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, combobox, filter

Sorry if title isn't very clear.
My problem is I have about 10 comboboxes. I want the user to be able to choose whatever he wants from one or two or whatever he likes from the provided 10 comboboxes, and the data gridview will filter the results according to what he choose.

If I used "AND", it will mean that the user "must" choose from all the provided ten comboboxes, Part of my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged
     Me.CSBindingSource.Filter = "[product] = '" & ComboBox3.Text & "' and [color] = '" & ComboBox4.Text & "' and [pattern] = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "'"
End Sub
```

He must choose from product and pattern and color and I want to give the customer the 
freedom to choose from whatever combobox provided as he wants, like only color and pattern.

and with "OR", it will just update the data gridview according to only one chosen combobox from all the 10.

So in short, I want the customer to choose from the combobox he wants not from all the choices and the results will be filtered according to what he enters.
Please help.

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express.

Comment: the cbo selected index changed event is probably not the right place for that - you need a button click where the user indicates they are done.  There is no sense formulating the filter in CBO3 event when you have no idea of the order and whether 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 represent final choices.  Wait until they click APPLY or whatever then construct the filter.  What that many choices you will likely find some are exclusive of each other

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you give me an example of how the could should be like? I'm still early in coding